# How do I build an alarm app using react where I can trigger the alarm remotely?

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, firebase

I want to build an app where I can send alarms to my phone using my computer. I was thinking of using firebase and sending a notfication type thing to trigger the alarm on my phone, but I don't think that would work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome 22asurya. I simply suggest you to try your idea.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for responding! How do you think I would go about doing that. I'm still in highschool and have just started with React and would really love some help.

Comment: Computer side : MERN with firebase to create and store your alarms. 
Phone side : react-native push notification with firebase.